# Where I can find the tnsnames.ora file for my Oracle Windows client?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, client

I installed Oracle client for my Windows 7 machine. I can connect to a remote Oracle database using Toad for Oracle using the direct method (giving host, port and service name for the connection).

Now I tried to find the `tnsnames.ora` file from the Oracle client oracle home, but could not find it. I could not find a `NETWORK\ADMIN` folder in `ORACLE_HOME` (C:\app\myaccount\product\11.2.0\client_1).

Where is this file located?

Comment: That's the default location; however, if you set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable, that location will be used instead.

Comment: I could find it here:


C:\USER_NAME\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

Answer (score 0):

At least for older releases, I'd generally just create my own. It's a plain text file but you probably need to start with an [example](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora).